# MySQL - remove specified character

Tags: mysql

I have a string `77681211132`. How to remove specified char `1` (index 8) and `6` (index 3) ? Char position is random.
Expected output is `778121132`.

Or How to remove first occurance specified char ? Example if I have string `77681211132`, how to remove first '1' char ? And the expected result is `7768211132`

If I use Replace, it will remove all of `1`.

Comment: Hint: Take the part of the string before the index and the part after and concatenate them.

Comment: Use `INSTR` to find the position and `SUBSTRING` to get out whatever is before it and whatever is after it.

Answer (score 0):

The following query removed the first '1' char occurence it finds.

```
DECLARE
 @thestring varchar(15),
 @firststring varchar(15),
 @secondstring varchar(15)

SET @thestring = '77681211132'

SELECT @firststring = SUBSTRING(@thestring, 0, LEN(@thestring) - 1 - INSTR(@thestring, '1'))

SELECT @firststring 

SELECT @secondstring = SUBSTRING(@thestring, INSTR(@thestring, '1') + 1, LEN(@thestring) - INSTR(thestring, '1'))

SELECT @firststring + @secondstring
```

Answer (score -1):

replace 111 with 11

or use the 
 Left()
and 
 Right() 
string operators to make a new string without the character to be removed from the left and right part out of the old string